# Javascript to clean html codes and use alphanumeric only in return

Tags: javascript, regex

i need a little help, figuring out my javascript output format

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html><head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>cleaner</title>

 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function show (text){
 var userInput = document.getElementById('textbox').value;
 userInput = userInput.replace(/\W/g, '');
 userInput = userInput.replace(/ /gi,", ");
 document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = userInput;
 }
 </script>

 </head>
 <body>
 <input type='textbox' name='textbox' id='textbox' value="Title Here"/>
 <input type=button name=button value="OK" onClick="show()"/>
 <div id="text"></div></body></html>
```

my input

```
 & ^A % - _ ^ % clean* this$ keyword-
```

my result is

```
 A_cleanthiskeyword
```

i want a result like this

```
 a, clean, this, keyword
```

what should i add in my replace code?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please check this code this will works for you

```
         <!doctype html>
             <html><head>
             <meta charset="utf-8">
             <title>cleaner</title>

             <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function show ()
{
    var userInput = document.getElementById('textbox').value;
        var num = userInput.indexOf('A');
      userInput    =  userInput.match(/[a-z]+/gi).join(", ").toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '');
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = userInput.substring(num-1);

     }
             }
             </script>

             </head>
             <body>
             <input type='textbox' name='textbox' id='textbox' value="Title Here"/>
             <input type=button name=button value="OK" onClick="show()"/>
             <div id="text"></div>
        </body></html>
```

Here is link for JSFiddle for your code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bzdnm/1062/)

Comment: works too!, how can i remove the single character in there the a,

Comment: @Tubestore Check now both link and code is updated.Is this you want?

Comment: As an alternative, you can use `(userInput.match(/[a-z]+/gi)+'').toLowerCase()`, which saves you A TON of work.

Comment: sagar the original output gives me  a, clean, this, keyword. I just want to remove the letter a,  so only clean, this, keyword is the result. is this possible?

Comment: @Tubestore Please explain i am not getting what you want?

Comment: @sagar43 codes above are working
which formats the result like this
---> a, clean, this, keyword <---
i just want to remove the letter -> a, <- which is a single character, not relevant for my keywords
so final result would be --> clean, this, keyword <--

Comment: @Tubestore Plz check now.It will gives you your desired output.

Comment: got it working userInput = userInput.match(/[a-z]{3,}/gi).join(", ").toLowerCase();

Comment: yes that can work too.
@Tubestore Please mark answered if you get your output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function show (text){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('textbox').value;
    userInput = userInput.match(/[a-z]+/gi).join(", ").toLowerCase();
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = userInput;
}
```

Comment: last question what should i add to remove the single character in tehre? the a, for example

Comment: @Tubestore change `userInput.match(...)` to `userInput.match(/[a-z]{n,}/gi)` where n is minimum number of characters.

Comment: got it now ceath, thanks to you userInput = userInput.match(/[a-z]{3,}/gi).join(", ").toLowerCase();